# Firebase realtime database order data and get last records

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase realtime database and this is my structure.

[image]

My question is how can i get last 20 messages ordered by createdAt for every group.
Any suggestions?

```
function getLastMessages(userId: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();

        dbRef.child("Users").child(userId).get().then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                console.log("No data available");
                resolve([]);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
            console.error(error);
        });
    });
}
```

I cant figure out how to fetch last 20 records ordered by createdAt for every group.

Comment: Can you show what you already tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!    So you want to get the latest 20 messages across all groups? That is not going to be possible with your current data structure, as Firebase can only query across a flat list of messages and you have two unknown levels in your JSON under the UID before you get to the createdAt`: group ID and message ID. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested